# Assertions in Swift

Tags: swift, assert, assertions

I tested assertions in Swift, but I'm little bit confused. Can you please explain to me a difference between `assert`, `assertionFailure` and `fatalError` functions?

I know about `@noreturn` attribute ([nicely explained](http://www.theboffinlab.com/lab-notes/swift-fatalerror-switch-statements) by Seven Oglesby), but I don't understand, when are these functions evaluated and when they are ignored.

Functions `assert` and `fatalError` occurred only in debug mode, I tested this behaviour and it's true. But `assertionFailure` stops program in release configuration too. In documentation stays:

> A fatal error occurred and program execution should stop in debug mode. In optimized builds this is a noop.

Then I don't understand, why isn't evaluation of this method in non-debug mode ignored. Does anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `assert` is evaluated only in debug mode, but `fatalError` occurs regardless of configuration. This is intentional.

However, `assertionFailure` also occurs regardless of configuration, despite the documentation you quote. As far as I can tell, either the behavior of `assertionFailure` is incorrect, or the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: For me `fatalError` occurs only in debug mode.

Comment: That's even stranger, because for me `fatalError` definitely works in release mode.

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 6.2 and now  `fatalError` works in release mode for me too.

Comment: Thank goodness! This makes sense now: `assert` and `assertionFailure` are for debug only, and `precondition` and `fatalError` are for all configurations.